# Creating Surrogate Key table with other unique constraints

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am self-taught for database design and MYSQL. Thank you for looking at my question. I am currently have a database looks like this in `mySQL`:

[image]

The reason I used a composite key is I want keep `Owner` and `DevName` unique all the time.
One problem I can see is that I need to use two foreign keys all the time so `Data1` table is not normalized.

So I made a table looks like this, making another table that has a surrogate key table.

[image]

Does this look okay? I am not sure making new table is really a good idea...

Is there any to make them in a single table that has a surrogate key, keeping a combination of `Owner` and `DevName` unique like this?:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Device3` and `Data3` looks good to me. I wouldn't mess with adding an extra table unless there was some compelling reason to. And likely any compelling reason to create third table boils down to just dealing with the composite foreign key, like in the original Device/Data1 model.

It seems like all that is missing is UNIQUE constraint. You can add a UNIQUE constraint (i.e. UNIQUE INDEX) on the combination of `owner` and `devname` columns. e.g.

```
 CREATE TABLE device3 
 ( id       INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 , owner    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL COMMENT ''
 , devname  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL COMMENT ''
 , ...

 , UNIQUE KEY device3_UX1 (owner, devname)

 ) ...
```

Or, if you already have the `device3` table created, you can just add add a unique index to the existing table. e.g.

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX device3_UX1 ON device3 (owner, devname)
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. Oh I thought that query makes a combination `id`, `owner`, and `devname` unique and I does not match my requirement. But it actually works well :) Thank you.

Just a simple question, so `UNIQUE INDEX` and `UNIQUE KEY` are identical? There is no difference?

Comment: Yes, identical in MySQL. (Other databases make distinctions between a unique CONSTRAINT and unique INDEX.  For example, Oracle allows a unique constraint to be enforced using a non-unique index. But the (MySQL) InnoDB storage engine won't do that. You need to create a unique index to enforce a unique constraint. In MySQL, these two statements are equivalent:  `ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT foo_UX1 UNIQUE KEY (bar,baz)`  and `CREATE INDEX foo_UX1 ON  foo (bar,baz)`.